# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\LandingController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8, this is my error message:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\LandingController] does not exist.

[image: error image]

The code in `route/web.php`:

```php
Route::resource('/', LandingController::class);
```

In my `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // $this->configureRateLimiting();

        // $this->routes(function(){
        //     Route::middleware('web')
        //         ->namespace($this->namespace)
        //         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
            
            // Route::prefix('api')
            //     ->middleware('api')
            //     ->namespace($this->namespace)
            //     ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));


        // });

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "API" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

I have seen similar questions in StackOverflow but I still get this error.

Answer (score 4):

The protected `$namespace` isn't needed if you're using the callable syntax. Since `::class` returns the fully qualified class name with the namespace already appended, i.e.

`LandingController::class` will be the string `App\Http\Controllers\LandingController`, adding the `$namespace` will append `App\Http\Controller` to that, thus becoming `App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\LandingController`.

Laravel now comments out the default `$namespace` in version 8 and above in favor of using the callable `::class` syntax instead, since it provides better support in IDE's¹, and is generally a cleaner practice.

If the `$namespace` is added back, the callable syntax won't work since it'll double up the namespace, as per your error, the namespace is only really needed if you want to use the old string syntax of `LandingController` instead of `LandingController::class`.

Source: ¹[Automatic Controller Namespace Prefixing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing)

Answer (score 0):

See how you are getting **App\Http\Controllers**\App\Http\Controllers\LandingController

Its a double up. generally you are missing a prefix or affix `\` e.g. `protected $namespace = '\App\Http\Controllers';`

Comment: when i give prefix \ and show this error Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the callable syntax, `$namespace` isn't needed. So just comment out/remove this line:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your route as follow:

```
Route::resource('/', [LandingController::class]);
```

For more information about this bug, please follow the following link:
https://litvinjuan.medium.com/how-to-fix-target-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel-8-f9e28b79f8b4

Comment: How is `namespace App\Providers` for `RouteServiceProvider` wrong ? What ?

Comment: The answer was updated, you can use it now.